# LINQ: Compare two list based on their properties and return items that match certain conditions

Tags: c#, linq, list, windows-phone-8

Say I have two list `List<NewTile>` and `List<OldTile>`. The `List<OldTile>` always contains more items than the `List<NewTile>`.

```
public class NewTile
{
    public Uri Navigation { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }    
}

public class OldTile
{
    public String Scheme { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }    
}
```

The `Navigation` property always contains the `Scheme` string for example.That's how items are related between those two lists.

```
Scheme = "wikipedia"
Navigation = "/Pages/BlankPage.xaml?Scheme=wikipedia"
```

I want to get all items from `List<NewTile>` where their Navigation property does not match any of them `Scheme` string from `List<OldTile>`. How do I do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<NewTile> filtered = newTiles // get me all new tiles...
    .Where( 
        newTile => // ...for which it's true that...
            oldTiles
                .All( // ...for all the old tiles...
                    oldTile => 
                        !newTile.Navigation.OriginalString.EndsWith("?Scheme=" + oldTile.Scheme))); 
                        // ...this condition is met.
```

Computational complexity of this is O(n2) I believe, so careful with handling large lists.

**EDIT:**

As for parsing the parameters (without HttpUtility), this can be done with an **Uri** and a **Regex**.

The trick is that since you only have a relative `Uri`, you  need to create an absolute one on the spot.

The following method worked for me:

```
    string GetScheme(string relativeUri)
    {
        string fakeSite = "http://fake.com"; // as the following code wouldn't work on relative Uri!
        Uri uri = new Uri(fakeSite + relativeUri);
        string query = uri.Query;
        string regexPattern = Regex.Escape("?Scheme=") + "(?<scheme>\\w+)";
        Match match = new Regex(regexPattern).Match(query);
        if (match.Captures.Count > 0)
        {
            return match.Groups["scheme"].Value;
        }
        return String.Empty;        
    }
```

Comment: Helpful but `Scheme` does not always `EndWith` in the `Navigation`. There may be extra string appended in `Navigation`

Comment: @PutraKg all right :) The best I could come up on the spot is fiddling with Uri + Regex (I updated my question). I'm not sure if the regex is perfect (probably case insensitivity should be taken care of, for example), but that's some starting point. Of course without `HttpUtility` it's still just a hack.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Where` + `Any` and `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to check whether or not the query-string is linked with the `Scheme`:

```
var newNotInOld = newTiles
    .Where(nt => !oldTiles
        .Any(ot => ot.Scheme.Equals(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(nt.Navigation.ToString())["Scheme"], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` and `using System.Web`.

Since you're using windows phone you don't have `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`. So could try this approach: http://dotnetautor.de/blog/2012/06/25/WindowsPhoneParseQueryString.aspx

Apart from that you can also use string methods or regex. For example:

```
 var newNotInOld = newTiles
  .Where(nt => !oldTiles
    .Any(ot => {
       string url = nt.Navigation.ToString();
       int index = url.IndexOf('?');
       bool containsScheme = false;
       if (index >= 0)
       {
           string queryString = url.Substring(++index);
           containsScheme = queryString.Split('&')
             .Any(p => p.Split('=')[0].Equals("Scheme", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) 
                    && p.Split('=').Last().Equals(ot.Scheme, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
       }
       return containsScheme;
   }));
```

Comment: Good one but I am developing for Windows Phone. The `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` does not seem to be available.

Comment: @PutraKg: i don't know if it works but it seems to be what you're looking for: http://dotnetautor.de/blog/2012/06/25/WindowsPhoneParseQueryString.aspx Apart from that you could also use string methods in above query, for example `EndsWith` or even `String.Split` on `=`.